# UISearch layout is different on different iPhones

Tags: ios, swift

On my storyboard, I add a UISearchBar and below that I added a table view. On iPhone 8, I am seeing the UISearchBar right below the navigation bar/header and on iPhone 5s and on iPad and I seeing some space between navigation bar/header and the UISearchBar.

***Image showing iPhone 5s on left and iPhone 8 on right:***
[image]

***UISearchBar on ViewController on the storyboard***
[image]

***UITableView on ViewController on the storyboard***
[image]

***Constraints on that view***
[image]

Any idea what could be happening?

***EDIT:***
I tried wrapping up both search bar and table view in UIStackView and added constraints around UIStackView so I don't have to add constraints for search bar and table view, but this time the search bar doesn't show up at all on the screen.
[image]

***Screen with UIStackView***
[image]

Comment: Do you have a constraint for the top of the search bar?

Comment: I wrapped them up in Stack view, but now search bar doesn't show up at all. I did add constraints around stack view.

Comment: Shouldn’t need a stack view to show a table view and search bar. Making it way too complicated. Pin the search bar under the navigation bar. Set a height for search bar. Pin the table view under the search and to the bottom of view.

Answer (score 0):

Did you check it without UITableView? 
Maybe it changes its position only seemingly? 
Go to simulator -> window -> unmark 'show device bezels' and add 'pixel accurate' ( cmd + 2)

Comment: I did what you suggested. The search bar still stays in the place... It moves up only when I try to pull it up and that's mostly because of the scroll bar.